# Karate Gatling - How to run Gatling tests using Maven uber jar

Tags: karate

We are using Maven shade plugin in our POM to create a uber jar. I kept the simulation/gatling tests under src->main->java and mentioned that folder structure under gatling-maven-plugin. However when i run the tests in CI pipeline with docker, the simulation class(PerformanceSimulation) is not getting detected. I am not sure if we need to specify a transformer main class separately under shade plugin to start the Gatling tests. The karate version I am using is 0.9.5. Please help. 
Below is my plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <simulationsFolder>src/main/java</simulationsFolder>
                <includes>
                    <include>gatling.PerformanceSimulation</include>
                </includes>
                <runMultipleSimulations>true</runMultipleSimulations>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I've never tried this, no idea. see if any dependency in `test` scope should be moved to `compile` or `runtime`